# What do the symbols -, < and > mean?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, pipe

I read this example in a book:

```
 cp /bin/cat proj33
 echo -n x | ./proj33 - pipe33a > pipe33b &
./proj33 <pipe33b >pipe33a &
```

What do the symbols `-`, `>` and `<` mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `>` is I/O redirection; it sends the standard output of the command (`./proj33`) to the file `pipe33b`.

The `<` symbol is also I/O redirection; it sends the standard input of the command (`./proj33` again) from the file `pipe33b`.

The `-` is just an argument.  It is often treated by commands as an indication to read standard input instead of a file.  In this context, it is likely that `proj33` normally requires a file as its first argument, but it reads from the pipe when the argument is `-`.  Sometimes, the `-` is used to indicate standard output.  In extreme cases, you can get one `-` indicating standard input and one indicating standard output on a single command. With GNU `tar`, you could have `tar -c -f - -T -` with the output being written to standard output (`-f -`) and the list of files to be archived read from standard input (`-T -`).

If you see `--`, that is very different; it indicates the 'end of options' for the command; anything that follows is not an option, even if it starts with a dash `-`.

Comment: so suppose I have a file called x.txt and I wrote this command echo x.txt | cat - , why isn't it typing the content of x.txt file ?

Comment: Because `echo` simplies echoes its arguments, all of them on one line, separated by spaces.  And `cat -` reads what it is sent on standard input and copies it to standard output.  You either need `cat x.txt` or something like `nextcmd < x.txt` where `nextcmd` was the command which `cat` was providing its output to (which avoids the UUOC — Useless Use of Cat — Award).  In extremis (not in this context), you might use `echo x.txt | xargs cat | nextcmd` to get a lot of file names relayed to `cat`.  `xargs` is useful, but not for the problem we're mainly discussing.